# Replace text in each line between two backward slashes at a certain point of the line

Tags: notepad++

the problem is pretty simple. I have a .m3u8 playlist file, that I want to convert to relative path.however the issue comes at this:

\Music\Foo Fighters\One By One\All my life.mp3

I want to remove what is after \Music\ but before the file name "All my life .mp3" , however per each line the artist and album is different ,they all follow the format of \Music\Artist name\Album\,  I want to remove the artist name and album part and just leave the \music\filename.mp3

I have tried replace tool and modified a bit but I have no idea how to deal with the conditions above.

Comment: Sounds like a job for Find and Replace and regex. https://superuser.com/a/1262661/389621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First open your file by Notepad++
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what:`(\\Music\\)(.+\\)`
- Replace with:`\1`
- Match case: Checked
- Wrap around: Checked
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd> when you're really sure.

The first capturing group (\Music\) matches `\Music\`. The second capturing group (.+\) matches  `Foo Fighters\One By One\`.

And we have a full match like `\Music\Foo Fighters\One By One\` replaced by the first group using `\1`.